# jQuery changing <img> src with $(selector).prop takes a long time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector, image

So there's no issue with this code functionality itself. I have something like this:

```
<div>
    <div><img id="imageToChange" src="/path/image.png" /></div>
    <div id="textToChange">Text</div>
</div>
```

I have another part of my code, that changes the image src/text with jQuery.

```
function changeImage() {
    $('#imageToChange').prop('src', '/path/image2.png');
    $('#textToChange').html('New Text');
}
```

As you may expect, this works exactly as I expect it to. But with 1 quirk.

In all the main browsers (chrome/FF/IE). The image takes a long time to change.

So for example, when I call changeImage(), the text will change instantly, but the image may not change until *1-2 seconds later*. (Not large images by any stretch, about ~6KB, and local)

I haven't found anyone else really complaining about it, but what I'm wondering is if there's any way to speed up the changing of the image src? Perhaps a better way to do it?

This is jquery 1.8.0 as well.

Thanks

Comment: What do you see in Firebug's network tab?

Comment: I've never seen this behaviour. Is it possible you can reproduce in a fiddle?

Comment: Try setting the `src` of already loaded `img`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have seen this behavior before. The delay is caused by the image not being cached and the subsequent load time. The only solutions I know of:

1. Preload your images with JavaScript Image objects.
2. Handle the [load event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) on the image and update the text after the image as loaded. Note jQuery lists some issues to watch out for:

> Caveats of the load event when used with images
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load()
>   shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of
>   images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with
>   this that should be noted. These are:
>
> - It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
> - It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
> - It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
> - Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: Thanks. Every other answer is generally correct, I ended up both creating javascript image objects and using the load event (because I noticed occasionally they still would free from the cache). Seems to work well so far, no issues.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to try altering the attribute using the jquery `.attr` function. If I recall correctly the `src` tag of an image is an attribute not a property. Although both `.prop` and `.attr` do relatively the same function, to ensure consistent behavior between browsers you may want to use the `.attr` tag instead.

```
$('#imageToChange').attr('src', '/path/image2.png');
```

As far as the delay goes, this could be due to the size of the image. The browser has to make a GET request to the server for the image and then paint the DOM with it. If the image is large, it could cause a time lapse between when the code changes the source and when the new image is properly written to the DOM. If the image is large, you may want to consider scaling it down or optimizing it for web use.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can pre-load the image using the Javascript Image object.

In the head of your document put

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   img2 = new Image();
   img2.src = "/path/image2.png";
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

it is likely the load time of your images. if this is the case, loading the image the first time should be the only slow one. a follow up load, after changing the image to something else, would be fast.

```
 $('#imageToChange').prop('src', '/path/image1.png');
 //slow, need to fetch image
 $('#imageToChange').prop('src', '/path/image2.png');
 //slow, need to fetch image
 $('#imageToChange').prop('src', '/path/image1.png');
 //fast, it already has this image
```

As a solution, you could try preloading your images. Or, better yet, use [css sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

Answer (score 2):

when you change the src of the image you fetch another image file. it makes an HTTP request for the new image, so it needs to load before showing it. could this be it?

btw, for this reason you can pre-load the image with js. either add

```
<img src="path/to/image.jpg" style="display: none" />
```

to your html or using JS

```
var im = new Image(1,1);
im.src = "path/to/image.jpg";
```

this way the image will be cached

Answer (score 2):

It's the delay of network. Try this:

```
<div>
    <div><img id="imageToChange" src="/path/image.png" /></div>
    <div id="textToChange">Text</div>
</div>
<img src='/path/image2.png' style='display:none'>
```